# Reading mail data from powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm trying to read some data from a .pst file using powershell and I can't seem to extract some attributes for mail items, specifically:

recipients, sender, cc, bcc, body

for some reason when I try to access these properties from code it shows up as blank. Most of the other properties show up file (subject, attachments etc...)

I'm using the following code:

```
$objOutlook = new-object -ComObject Outlook.Application

$ns = $objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

$ns.AddStore($pst.FullName)

$folders = $ns.Folders

$archiveStore = $ns.Folders[$pst.Name.Replace(".pst","")]
```

from there I just use Folders and Items recursively to get my mail items.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This returns the sender for me.

```
$archiveStore.Items | %{$_.SenderName}
```

Which property are you using to fetch the recipients,sender,cc,bcc,body?

Answer (score 0):

Where and how do you run a PowerShell script? And what code exactly do you use to fetch the property values?

The fact is that Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.